# Visualization of patient flow and competition betweeen hospitals

Tags: data-visualization

I'm working on a project. The goal is to graphically represent the flow of patients between hospitals and also graphically represent competition between hospitals. All this in cartography. I detail. It is a question of representing on a map the geographical origin of the patients who go to hospital A.  I should also identify other hospitals that recruit in the same areas where hospital A recruits. Elsewhere I should identify the zones of influence of Hospital A (the zones where it recruits the most) and then identify all the other hospitals where residents of that (zone of influence) also go. I have to quantify all these flows. So I'm looking for the appropriate tools to make these graphical representations. I'm not sure where to look, how to look. Such tools seem to be rare in the field of health care. Could someone give me some leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Python](https://www.python.org/), [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) and a cartography library such as [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/#). But it really depends on your personal preferences. For example, if you are familiar with JavaScript, then [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) may be a good choice.

*Where to look?*

This Wikipedia article could be a good starting point: [Flow map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_map)

*How to look?*

Do a Google picture search for *flow map*, *2-dimensional histogram*, *choropleth map*, *contour plot*, *geographic data*, or some such terms, and if you find an image that comes close to the kind of visualization you want, see which tools where used to create it.

Comment: Thank you Arne for your suggestions, they helped me a lot. I'm working with R and he offers flow visualization tools that are not so bad.